# Hello phpmyadmin error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to access my server locally.

I get an error (incorrect permissions on the configuration file either should not be able to modify it!). Has someone see this before and how do set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin want config.inc.php to be not world writable. Just chmod 0755 the file

```
$ chmod 0755 config.inc.php
```

Comment: THANKSSSSS :))))

http://marioabril.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/nic3b1o-rezando.jpg